# Uses of the internal logic of a topos in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, topos-theory

I see why topoi arise naturally in AG, but I'm having a hard time finding examples, if any, of the application of their more logical side to geometric questions.

> I'm looking for examples of proofs in AG using the internal logic of topoi, or an explanation of why there aren't (m)any.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: I'm looking for examples of proofs in AG using the internal logic of topoi, or an explanation of why there aren't (m)any.

Comment: Ingo Blechschmidt's thesis contains numerous examples: https://github.com/iblech/internal-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several such examples (although not being well-versed in the subject, I can't say how serious a role internal reasoning plays in algebraic geometry, just that examples exist). A few can be found in the answers to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394194/what-does-a-proof-in-an-internal-logic-actually-look-like?rq=1). Of particular interest is Ingo Blechschmidt's answer; he shows how the statement

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module locally of finite type. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free iff its rank is constant.

can be proved using internal logic, roughly as follows:

- Reasoning internally, we translate the question to one about usual modules inside the topos of sheaves on $X$.
- This reduces the problem to the task of proving a linear algebra fact constructively, which one can do.

I think this provides a very nice example of what internal logic can do: it lets you answer a complicated question by interpreting it as a conceptually much simpler question *inside a different topos*.

(Actually, I guess this is more accurately a description of the use of the internal *language* of the topos, and not the internal *logic* per se; that is really the second bullet point.)

---

EDIT: I apologize for bumping an old post, but today(!) Ingo Blechschmidt posted to the arXiv [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.03685.pdf) which seems to address exactly this.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm curious whether a theorem in algebraic geometry has every been *first* proven using internal logic, rather than being proved initially via standard means and then reproved (possibly more elegantly) by internal logic.